# error getting all posts associated with a tag laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

im trying to get posts associated with a tag and i am  getting this error

```
public function tag(Tag $tag)
    {
        $posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag) {
            $query->whereIn('tags.id', $tag);
        })->get();
        return  view('posts.tag', compact('posts'));
    }
```

im getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from `posts` where exists (select * from `tags` inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id` where `posts`.`id` = `post_tag`.`post_id` and `tags`.`id` in (1, HHHHH, 2021-08-08T13:00:05.000000Z, 2021-08-08T13:00:05.000000Z, 1, 1)))
```

Comment: try with `$query->whereIn('tags.id', [$tag->id]);`

Comment: WhereIn method accept an array, not a string `whereIn('tags.id', [$tag->id])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But you can just get posts from Tag itself:

```
$posts = $tag->posts;
return  view('posts.tag', compact('posts'));
```

In your query two mistakes: return statement and tag id:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag) {
    return $query->whereIn('tags.id', [$tag->id]);
})->get();
```

Comment: It is a good answer. In this way you also can use query builder on `$tag->posts` by accessing it as a method: `$tags->posts()->where('title', 'like', 'T%')->get();`

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
$query->whereIn('tags.id', [$tag->id]);
```

Or use only `where`

```
$query->where('tags.id', $tag->id);
```